# Divergence of a double integral of a exponential

Tags: real-analysis, integration, iterated-integrals

> **Problem:** Solve the double integral
>   $$I:=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} dx dy\ f(x,y),$$
>   where $f(x,y) = e^{-i a(x - y)}$ if $y > x$ and zero otherwise ($a$ is only a positive real constant).

So, I think I have

$$I=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} dy \int_{-\infty}^{y} dx\ e^{-ia(x - y)}.$$

But this integral diverges. Is there some way to compute it?

Comment: Is $i$ the imaginary unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: let $u=(x+y)/2,v=(x-y)/2$, then $x=u+v,y=u-v$ and $dxdy=-2dudv$
$$I:=\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} dx dy\ g(x-y)=-2\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} dv\ g(2v)\right)du$$
$$=-2\left(\int _{-\infty}^{\infty}du\right) \left(\int _{-\infty}^{\infty} dv\ g(2v)\right)$$

Comment: But this integral of $u$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is not well defined, isn't it?

Comment: that is why it is divergent.$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}du=+\infty$